# Snowflake 403 error using Google as Identity Provider IdP

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to configure google IdP on my Snowflake following this tutorial from Snowflake community:
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/configuring-g-suite-as-an-identity-provider?t=1630354048853

After the whole configuration is complete when I click on the SSO button on the login page
[SSO Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPcio.png)

I receive the following error:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEfC3.png)

I have already double-checked the SAML configuration on both platforms
[SAML Configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVAEZ.png)

And APP configuration on Google seems correct
[Google Snowflake App configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxurP.png)
[Google Snowflake App configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooRP1.png)

But the 403 error still persists.
How can I identify exactly where is the problem (Snowflake or Google) and how to fix it?
Is there any log I should be checking or any configuration missing?
Thanks!

Comment: On the Google side, what is the SSO URL or Application Callback URL value set to?One of the reason for the error could be that this is not set with /fed/login but is only having https://<account>.<region>.snowflakecomputing.com

Secondly, the certificate which is added to Snowflake security integration object is not correct. This can be checked from the metadata file downloaded from Google.

Answer (score 5):

We ran into this error as well, but fortunately the solution was rather simple in our case:

- Either use incognito mode
- Or log out & back in to the Google account

Afterwards, it works flawlessly!

Answer (score 3):

I found [this article](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6301076?hl=en) from Google Support:

> 403 app_not_configured_for_user To resolve the 403
> app_not_configured_for_user error:
>
> Verify that the value in the saml:Issuer tag in the SAMLRequest
> matches the Entity ID value configured in the SAML Service Provider
> Details section in the Admin console. This value is case-sensitive.

Comment: Thank you Suzy, I've confirmed the SAML and both match(including the case-sensitive letters)m still the error remains.

Comment: Hmm, what does your SAML request look like? For example, it should have a field like this and you want it to match your Entity ID in your Google configuration:   <saml:Issuer>https://<account_name>.eu-west-2.aws.snowflakecomputing.com</saml:Issuer>

Comment: And do feel free to open a Snowflake Support case if you continue to get stuck.  I don't want you to put too much information about your configuration here - a ticket would be safer.

Comment: Hi! Yes it looks just like that, do you know if is there in snowflake any log I can use to track the SAML requests and payloads? thanks!

Comment: Not that I know of, but you can use any browser extension that does that like SAML Message Decoder. Here's a good article as well: 
https://snowflakecommunity.force.com/s/article/How-To-Obtain-a-SAML-Response-And-Use-It-To-Troubleshoot-SSO-Issues

Comment: Thank you so much, This article nail it.
The problem was this tag in the SAML payload:
<saml2:Audience>https://<account_name>.snowflakecomputing.com</saml2:Audience>. 
We're using https://<account_name>.eu-west-2.snowflakecomputing.com. but there should be no eu-west-2.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution!